# Dlookup retrieves a date wrong

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get a date in my database but when the day is less than 12, the month and the day are switched

Example: In the database 2012-02-10 (2 october 2012), the value I get when I do that:

`lastDateMill = Nz(DLookup("LastContactDate", "Mills", "MillID = " & lstMills.Column(0, i)), 0)`

is

```
lastDateMill = "10/02/2012"
```

So I thought that was only a format thing but when I do

```
Format(lastDateMill, "Long Date")
```

it equals "February-10-12"

This is how I update the date

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Mills SET LastContactDate = #" & SalesCallDate & "# WHERE MillID = " & lstMills.Column(0, i)
```

And the `SalesCallDate = "2/10/2012"` so the good date

So why the day and the month are switched?

The front end is `ms-access-2010` and the back end is on `SQL SERVER 2012`

Comment: It is disconcerting to type an answer only to find the question deleted, especially when it reappears.

Comment: Sorry sir, I closed it like 30 seconds cause I thought it was really obvious. You weren't lucky. I will go read some of you answers and upvote those I like lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SalesCallDate` variable contains a date as text:

SalesCallDate = "2/10/2012"

Apparently you intend the date format of that string to be `m/d/yyyy`, but it gets interpreted as `d/m/yyyy` format.

Store the string value in `yyyy/mm/dd` format to eliminate confusion due to locale issues ... `2012/02/10`

Since it turns out that `SalesCallDate` is actually a text box containing a date value, change your `UPDATE` approach to avoid date problems due to locale.

```
Dim strUpdate As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
strUpdate = "UPDATE Mills SET LastContactDate = " & _
    Format(Me.SalesCallDate, "\#yyyy-m-d\#") & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE MillID = " & Me.lstMills.Column(0, i)
Debug.Print strUpdate
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute strUpdate, dbFailonerror
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: Or store the the date in a date field.

Comment: It's already a date field, the format is short date. It's bounded with the database on another date field

Comment: No sorry, `SalesCallDate` is a textbox with a short date format bounded to a date field in the database and when there's a new sales call, the `saleCallDate` become the `lastContactDate`.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood SalesCallDate = "2/10/2012" to mean that SalesCallDate is string.  See if the edit I just made gets you closer to what you need.

Comment: You're welcome.  I used db.Execute instead of DoCmd.RunSQL because that removes any temptation to set SetWarnings off.  Also the dbFailonerror option will give you better error notification.  I'm assuming you will add an error handler to the final version of your code.

Comment: I just changed them all for `CurrentDb.Execute`. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this, by explicitly specifying a format

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Mills SET LastContactDate = #" & _
    Format$(SalesCallDate,"yyyy/mm/dd") & "# WHERE MillID = " & _
    lstMills.Column(0, i)
```

---

**UPDATE**:

Maybe there is better way to do it, that is independent of any formattings. The idea is to tranfer the date from table to table, without any combo-, list- or text in between. Therefore any conversion from a date type to string and then back to a date field is avoided.

If the tables can be joined (assuming that MillID is the bound field of the listbox):

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Mills " & _
  "INNER JOIN sourceTable ON Mills.MillID = sourceTable.MillID " & _
  "SET LastContactDate = sourceTable.SalesCallDate " & _
   "WHERE Mills.MillID = " & lstMills
```

Otherwise

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Mills SET LastContactDate = " & _
  "(SELECT SalesCallDate FROM sourceTable WHERE ID = " & sourceID & ")" _
  "WHERE Mills.MillID = " & lstMills
```